# Insert text in input field simulating human typing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have username and password field, I want to set text using javascript/jquery but if I use .val or .value it sets the text but when I click on the button to login it says field is required.  I tried to do .focus etc no help.  If I manually type in each field then it works.  I am trying to automate so I can login using a script.  It does not have to be login. lets say search field.  You have to manually type in before search button enables.  If I use .value .val etc it does not work.  I also tried following code it does not enable button.

```
function simulateTextEntry(inputField, textToEnter) {
    inputField.focus(); //focus input field
    inputField.value = ""; // Clear the input field

    // Simulate entering each character in the text
    for (var i = 0; i < textToEnter.length; i++) {
        var charCode = textToEnter.charCodeAt(i);

        // Simulate keydown event
        var keydownEvent = new Event('keydown');
        keydownEvent.keyCode = charCode;
        inputField.dispatchEvent(keydownEvent);

        // Simulate keypress event
        var keypressEvent = new Event('keypress');
        keypressEvent.keyCode = charCode;
        inputField.dispatchEvent(keypressEvent);

        // Update the input field's value
        inputField.value = inputField.value + textToEnter[i];

        // Simulate keyup event
        var keyupEvent = new Event('keyup');
        keyupEvent.keyCode = charCode;
        inputField.dispatchEvent(keyupEvent);
    }
}
```

0

here is a page you can test:

https://at.experitest.com/#/login

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js';
document.head.appendChild(script);

$("input[name*='username']").val("something");
$("input[name*='password']").val("something");
document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].click();
```

it will make login button disabled but if you manually type into the field it does perform validation.

Comment: Can you show us how the button works? Because it seems weird, that you would get a "field is required" message, if there is a value in the text input.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try to use Selenium or Puppeteer / Playwright framework, that emulates user behaviour.
For exmaple, in Selenium you can use native 'sendKeys' function on `WebElement`; in Puppeteer it would be `type` method.

It seems that the website you're interacting with has some event listeners or validation mechanisms that are not being triggered when you set the input values programmatically. In you case validation rely on `input` event.
So, after `keypress` you should dispatch it and validation would be passed.

```js
function simulateTextEntry(inputField, textToEnter) {
    inputField.focus();
    inputField.value = ""; 

    for (let i = 0; i < textToEnter.length; i++) {
        var charCode = textToEnter.charCodeAt(i);

        let keydownEvent = new Event('keydown', { keyCode: charCode });
        inputField.dispatchEvent(keydownEvent);

        let keypressEvent = new Event('keypress', { keyCode: charCode });
        inputField.dispatchEvent(keypressEvent);

        inputField.value = inputField.value + textToEnter[i];

        let inputEvent = new Event('input', { bubbles: true });
        inputField.dispatchEvent(inputEvent);

        let keyupEvent = new Event('keyup', { keyCode: charCode });
        inputField.dispatchEvent(keyupEvent);
    }
}

let usernameField = $("input[name*='username']");
let passwordField = $("input[name*='password']");

simulateTextEntry(usernameField, "something");
simulateTextEntry(passwordField, "something");

let loginButton = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
loginButton.click();
```